# Audio player not working in playlist

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an audio HTML5 player, since it is working fine on single audio but when I adding more audios some like :

```
1.Pitbull
2.Shakira
3.Bilal Saeed
```

Now, I click on PITBULL (ok working fine) but when I click on (Bilal Saeed or Shakira) another song all song will be playing instead of, pause the PITBULL and start SHAKIRA or Bilal Saeed.
Check it on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8dzd6bh4/20/)

Comment: Can you display your source code. With no source code I have nothing to debug to explain why you have this issue and offer a solution. Posting without source code will mean those who want to help will have to assume and recreate what they think you have. Please edit/update your question. Thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8dzd6bh4/20/ Yes the source is also available

Comment: And I also put source code in my Que. sir.

Comment: I see you added a link to JSFiddle, I was asking if you would mind placing the source code into your question. This allows me to read over the issue description while reading your source code. It doesn't matter. At least you have a link to display the source code. Some don't bother displaying anything at all.

Comment: Okay. I'll thankful to you if you make it for me what I want.